# Minifying javascript makes function un-callable

Tags: javascript, gulp, uglifyjs

I'm using gulp to build an asset pipeline for my project. I'm currently using `gulp-uglify` to minify javascript.

When Uglify processes my JS, it changes the function name, which makes it un-callable. Does anyone know how to prevent this from happening?

```
(function() { "use strict";

  function Ajax(params, url, callbackFunction) {
    this.params = params,
    this.url = url,
    this.callback = callbackFunction
  }

  Ajax.prototype.call = function() {
    $.ajax({
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "post",
      data: this.params,
      success: this.callback,
      error: this.callback
    });
  }
})();
```

becomes

```
!function(){"use strict";function t(t,a,s){this.params=t,this.url=a,this.callback=s}t.prototype.call=function(){$.ajax({contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",dataType:"json",type:"post",data:this.params,success:this.callback,error:this.callback})}}();
```

This changes the Ajax function to be called "t" and when I want to instantiate a new Ajax object, I get an `Uncaught ReferenceError: Ajax is not defined`

My calling code is

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var ajaxTest = new Ajax("google.com", {}, printTest);
  console.log(ajaxTest);
  Ajax.call();

  function printTest() {
    console.log("Hello");
  }
});
```

which gets minified to

```
$(document).ready(function(){function o(){console.log("Hello")}var l=new Ajax("google.com",{},o);console.log(l),Ajax.call()});
```

Comment: Your code should fail both before and after minification. `Ajax` is not global in either case, so it shouldn't be accessible within the document ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with the minifying process. The `Ajax` identifier is local to the scope, so it's not reachable outside the scope anyway. Any code inside that scope that would use the `Ajax` identifier would be minified to use the `t` identifier.

If you want to use the `Ajax` identifier outside the scope, you can return it from the function wrapper:

```
var Ajax = (function() { "use strict";

  function Ajax(params, url, callbackFunction) {
    this.params = params,
    this.url = url,
    this.callback = callbackFunction
  }

  Ajax.prototype.call = function() {
    $.ajax({
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "post",
      data: this.params,
      success: this.callback,
      error: this.callback
    });
  };

  return Ajax;
})();
```

Now you can use the `Ajax` identifier in your other code. If the `Ajax` identifier that is outside the scope is changed by minifying the code, the code using it will also use that new identifier.

Comment: Thank you. That was the root issue. As an aside, uglifyjs has a parameter "mangle" that can be set to false to preserve variable names, which I just found out about.